# How to find derivative of this complex function

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

[image]

I have no idea how to differentiate this function with respect to z

I know about cr equation and derivative in forms of that. But i cant apply that.

Comment: Please, use MathJax (i.e. LaTeX commands) for mathematical notation.

Comment: Moreover, what do you mean by cr equation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Note that:
$$
\frac{\partial w}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+i\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}\qquad \mbox {and} \qquad
\frac{\partial w}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}+i\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}
$$

and remember that, if $w$ is analytic:

$$
\frac{d w}{d z}=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+i\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}-i\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}
=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}-i\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=
\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}+i\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}
$$